# How can we know whether rooms are free in google calendar?

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I was searching for an API that will help me in getting the rooms from google calendar.

While i was searching i found this url 
[Google Calendar Api, Is meeting Room available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33797752/google-calendar-api-is-meeting-room-available)

In this case the solution was go through each meeting room as a calendar and then to check whether the room is free for a given date and time or not. What i was having a doubt was when the number of events are too large. This would take a lot of time. Can anyone else suggest me a better option?