# Google Calendar API getting 'Cannot read property 'signIn' of null'

Tags: javascript, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to use Google's Calendar API to get info on specific calendar. I keep getting this error `Cannot read property 'signIn' of null`. I'm using the example online here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js.

Any idea why this is happening? And can someone give me a more simple way to get calendar data? Basically I want to know which rooms in my calendar feed are free to book. Can I do this using the calendar API?

```
const CLIENT_ID = '418414126140-u5u3r2ampke8egh7d2tk50ferkl8ri26.apps.googleusercontent.com';
const SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"];

app.factory('getCalendar', ['$q', function($q){
    return function checkAuth() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        function handleClientLoad() {
            gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
        }
        handleClientLoad();

        function initClient() {
            gapi.client.init({
              "client_id": CLIENT_ID,
              "scope": SCOPES
            }).then(function () {
                gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
            });
        }

        function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
            if (isSignedIn) {
                console.log("You are authorized");
                listUpcomingEvents();
            } else {
                console.log("You are not authorized");
            }
        }

        function listUpcomingEvents() {
            gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
                'calendarId': 'primary',
                'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
                'showDeleted': false,
                'singleEvents': true,
                'maxResults': 10,
                'orderBy': 'startTime'
            }).then(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                deferred.resolve(response);

            });
        }
        return deferred.promise;

    } //return ends here

}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);` instead of `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();`. You may refer with this sample [code](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/236) on how to use the Google JavaScript Client API Library to authenticate and interact with the API.

Also check this [related SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22057610/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-value-of-null) and see if it helps.

**UPDATE:**

*Any idea on how to check which rooms on your calendar are available or not?*

You may check on this link: [Google Calendar Api, Is meeting Room available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33797752/google-calendar-api-is-meeting-room-available)

> You will need to be authenticated as a user that has read-access to the room. Then you can take the resourceEmail field of the Calendar Resource API and use it as a calendarId in the [events.list()](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) Calendar API call.

Comment: Thanks. I found this tutorial online which is much easier to use compared to Google's documentation. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0rZmp3Ew_kA

Any idea on how to check which rooms on your calendar are available or not?