# Unable to call class function from promise's then Typescript / Angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, method-call

I'm trying to use Google Sheets Api from an angular project.

In my GoogleSheetsAPIService class the method initClient makes a promise call to gapi.client.init method successfuly, but from the promises then, I have to call to call the updateSigninStatus method of the class.

I'm using arrow notation to conserve the "this" context, but console always says "Cannot read property 'updateSigninStatus' of undefined".

**Here is my code:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

declare var gapi: any;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class GoogleSheetsAPIService {
  constructor() {}

  /**
   *  On load, called to load the auth2 library and API client library.
   */
  handleClientLoad() {
    gapi.load('client:auth2', this.initClient);
  }

  /**
   *  Initializes the API client library and sets up sign-in state listeners.
   */
  initClient() {
    gapi.client.init(environment.googleSheetsApiConfig).then(
      () => { **// Notice arrow notation to conserve this scope**
        // Listen for sign-in state changes.
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(this.updateSigninStatus); 
                                                    **// This fires the error**

        // Handle the initial sign-in state.
        this.updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
        **// This fires the error too**
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
      }
    );
  }

  /**
   *  Called when the signed in status changes, to update the UI
   *  appropriately. After a sign-in, the API is called.
   */
  updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
    if (isSignedIn) {
      console.log('signed in');
    } else {
      console.log('not signed in');
    }
  }
}
```

**and here is the error stack from browser**

```
zone-evergreen.js:171 Uncaught TypeError: **Cannot read property 'updateSigninStatus' of undefined**
    at google-sheets-api.service.ts:26 
    at e.Ar (cb=gapi.loaded_0:239)
    at $k (cb=gapi.loaded_0:242)
    at Vk (cb=gapi.loaded_0:242)
    at _.Gk.pT (cb=gapi.loaded_0:242)
    at Fk (cb=gapi.loaded_0:234)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:364)
    at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:123)
    at zone-evergreen.js:857
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
```

I think it could be a systax issue, but i'm ike newby with typescript, so any help is too apreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42099791/google-calendar-api-getting-cannot-read-property-signin-of-null seems to deal with a similar issue which may help.

Comment: Hi, Rob, thanks for your answer, unfortunatelly, the suggested issue says: "Try using gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus); instead of gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();" but I already have the suggestion applied and it doesn't work. Suggestion works for javascript, but I'm using typescript. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: gapi.load('client:auth2', this.initClient.bind(this)); - check if this helps

Comment: Hi, Andrii, that worked like a charm. Thanks a ton for your help, i'd like to get an reference or resource to understand why and how binding this works